# How to disable Main Window MenuBar

Tags: python, wxpython

In my wxpython APP, I want to disable Main window MenuBar (I actually don't know what it is called).

[image]

If I click that icon, this options are poped up. I want to stop this coming up, not disable items like `Move`, `Minimize`, `Close`. but the whole part.

Answer (score 0):

That is known as the System Menu. You can't actually remove the menu without removing all the buttons too. To do that, you'll have to use a series of style flags during your initialization of the wx.Frame:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class NoSystemMenuFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    There is no system menu, which means the title bar is there, but
    no buttons and no menu when clicking the top left hand corner
    of the frame
    """

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        no_sys_menu = wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX | wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN | wx.CLOSE_BOX
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="No System Menu", style=no_sys_menu)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = NoSystemMenuFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You can disable some of the settings in the menu, but those settings will also apply to the buttons too. Check out the following article which goes over the majority of the options:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/11/06/wxpython-101-using-frame-styles/

You might also find the documentation itself useful:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Frame.html#frame

Answer (score 0):

My method of working in such situations will be to create an Empty Menubar and set it as the menu bar like this:

```
empty_menu_bar = MenuBar()
frame.SetMenuBar(empty_menu_bar)
```

Since there are no menu items in the menu bar, it is not shown in the window.